# python3 create/open file case sensitive Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, case-sensitive

Tried interneting and checking the python3 documentation, but I can't seem to fix the following - I'm probably just missing a flag or something!

I want to create and edit files in the local directory . using python with case-sensitive file names: but I have the following behaviour:

```
~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("file.txt", "w")
>>> f.write("hello\n")
6
>>> f.close()
>>> del f
>>> f = open("File.txt", "w")
>>> f.write("BYE\n")
4
>>> f.close()
>>> del f
>>> quit()
~$ ls
Applications    Downloads       Movies       Public
Cloud           File.txt        Music        intel
Desktop         Jagex           Documents    Library
Documents       Library         Pictures
~$ cat File.txt 
BYE
~$ cat file.txt
cat: file.txt: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know where my "file.txt" [with 'hello\n'] file has gone?

Thanks!

Edit1: I'm using OSX Sierra 10.12.1 to be precise.

Comment: Are you using OS X?

Comment: Ahh yeah - sorry I meant to add that. Yes "OSX Sierra 10.12.1" to be precise :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not (directly) related to Python but to the OS and its filesystem. Unix-like (Linux and BSDs for example) have strict case sensitive file names: `file.txt` and `File.txt` are two different files. On the other hand on Windows, if a case insensitive version of the same name already exists, it will be opened instead of creating a new one. So on Windows, your code will have reopened (and erased because of the `w` mode) the same file. I have no access to a Mac, so I cannot say whether it is the same case.

But as you use Python 3.5, you can use the `x` mode for exclusive creation mode. In this mode, if the open call would have opened an existing file, you would get an error.

Your code could become:

```
~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("file.txt", "x")
>>> f.write("hello\n")
6
>>> f.close()
>>> del f
>>> f = open("File.txt", "x") # will eventually raise a IOError...
...
```

Comment: It's not so much the OS but the file system. If you mount a case insensitive (e.g. FAT32) file system on linux then file names will also be treated case insensitive when opening a file. Apples [HFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) is usually case insensitive, but case sensitivity is supported (can be turned on when formatting a partition)

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)

I'm glad it's not just a python coding error on my part! I am indeed running OSX (Sierra) so maybe this is part of the problem.

When following your code Serge, using the "x" option, I do raise an error as you predicted. But is there not a way for me to create both "file.txt"" and "File.txt" without raising an error, as separate objects? Or do I have to bite the bullet and only work with lower-case filenames?